# What's the .DS_Store file that keeps changing in my Visual Studio project on macOS?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, github

I notice when I make a small change to the application then a file called `<solution>/.DS_Store` is modified and I am prompted to push the new version of that in addition to other files. Is this needed and if not then should it be something that's in the `.gitignore` file and how can I add it there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`.DS_Store` file is related to macOS, not to Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store):

> In the [Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.) [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) operating system, **.DS_Store** is a file that stores custom attributes of its containing [folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(file_systems)), such as the position of [icons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icon_(computing)) or the choice of a background image. The name is an abbreviation of *Desktop Services Store*, reflecting its purpose. It is created and maintained by the [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) application in every folder, and has functions similar to the file [desktop.ini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop.ini) in [Microsoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows). Starting with a full stop (period) character, it is [hidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) in Finder and many Unix utilities. Its internal structure is [proprietary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_format).

It should almost certainly be ignored by your version control system. Add

```
.DS_Store
```

to your project's `.gitignore` file and then untrack the file by running

```
git rm --cached .DS_Store
```

and commit the change.

Comment: I see in some places in the gitignore,  there's a reference to *.xxx    Should I add a *.DS_Store or is just .DS_Store enough?

Comment: Just `.DS_Store`. It's not a file extension, it's [a hidden file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory). That's its whole name. You might want to add [some other patterns too](https://gitignore.io/api/macos). Those are for macOS; feel free to look up suggested ignores for your language, framework, IDE, etc.